# Spark not showing actual count listed in Cassandra

Tags: scala, apache-spark, cassandra, datastax, spark-cassandra-connector

After running Cassandra `count(*)` to a table I got the value **254617922** .But in `spark-shell`, I'm only getting **2865767** while running the same `count(*)`.

I tried to run in spark cluster and local machine but it shows the same value. What could be the reason?

Environment details:

- Cassandra : 3.11.0
- Spark :  2.2.0
- Connector : spark-cassandra-connector_2.11
- Scala :  2.12.1
- Java  : Java 1.8.0_101

Relevant code ran in spark-shell is:

```
$SPARK_HOME/bin/spark-shell \
  --conf spark.cassandra.connection.host=127.0.0.1 \
  --packages datastax:spark-cassandra-connector:2.0.3-s_2.11

import com.datastax.spark.connector._
import org.apache.spark.sql.cassandra._
import org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD
val rdd = sc.cassandraTable("key", "table")
println(rdd.count)
```

Comment: Spark doesn't support Scala 2.12 as of now.

Comment: Can you help me to suggest which version need to placed in my setup

Comment: I'm not sure if that is causing the problem but you should be using Scala 2.11

Comment: That large a discrepancy would lead me to believe they aren't even touching the same table or perhaps even cluster. Small variations are usually attributed to consistency level changes but your change indicates a huge amount of data is simply not read.

Comment: when I try to find the count(*) on  the same table in cqlsh it show the same value 2865767. But its not correct row count in my file. file has 2.5G data. after exporting the data from cassandra data size of the exported file 258mb. however exact row count shows (254617922 ) while load the date to cassandra with the copy command. I am stuck with my project. I hope I am playing only with 256mb data .. expect more more suggestion on this from you all great coders like RussS